# Inequalities next to systems of equations

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

$$EXP=\begin{cases}
n^3\left(\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}3\right\rfloor+24}{50}\right)&n\le15\\
n^3\left(\frac{n+14}{50}\right)&15\le n\le36\\
n^3\left(\frac{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor+32}{50}\right)&36\le n\le100\end{cases}$$
In this equation ([used to calculate Pokémon exp](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience#Relation_to_level)) there are 3 systems of equations, but there are inequalities next to them. Does this mean that for example we use the top equation when $$n\le15\\$$ and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what that means. This is an example of a [piecewise function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).

Comment: @DMcMor Thanks! If you want you can post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, that's exactly what that means.  This is an example of a [piecewise function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).  The idea is that sometime, as in this case, it's useful to have a different rule for assigning outputs depending on the value of the input.  Take a look at [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/c4lqljlzht) for a better idea of how each piece looks on the graph.